# How do I make an endless horizontal background in Swift?

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

```
import SpriteKit

class GameScene: SKScene {

    let bgline1 = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Line.png")
    let bgline2 = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Line.png")

    override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
        /* Setup your scene here */
        backgroundColor = SKColor.whiteColor()
        bgline1.anchorPoint = CGPointZero
        bgline1.position = CGPointZero
        bgline1.zPosition = 1
        bgline1.size = CGSizeMake(self.frame.size.width, self.frame.size.height)
        self.addChild(bgline1)

        bgline2.anchorPoint = CGPointZero
        bgline2.position = CGPointMake(bgline1.position.x-1, 0)
        bgline2.zPosition = 1
        bgline2.size = CGSizeMake(self.frame.size.width, self.frame.size.height)
        self.addChild(bgline2)
    }

    override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
        /* Called when a touch begins */

        for touch in (touches as! Set<UITouch>) {
            let location = touch.locationInNode(self)


        }
    }
    override func update(currentTime: CFTimeInterval) {

        /* Called before each frame is rendered*/
        bgline1.position = CGPoint(x: bgline1.position.x-4, y: bgline1.position.y)
        bgline2.position = CGPoint(x: bgline2.position.x-4, y: bgline2.position.y)

        if bgline1.position.x < -bgline1.size.width{
            bgline1.position = CGPointMake(bgline2.position.x + bgline2.size.width, bgline1.position.y)
        }
        if bgline2.position.x < -bgline2.size.width{
            bgline2.position = CGPointMake(bgline1.position.x + bgline1.size.width, bgline2.position.y)
        }
    }
}
```

This is my code for creating a scrolling horizontal endless background. It is supposed to make an endless background but it isn't. The code is not looping the first try but after that it does. I would like to know why it does not work and how should I fix it.

EDIT- Starts out with 2 nodes and a line and the fps is <20. Then the line ends and when it "runs out" the node count becomes 0 and fps becomes 60. Than after a few seconds the line pops back up and it runs perfectly like a endless scrolling background.

Comment: You need to explain what exactly isn't working. What is it doing? What isn't it doing?

Comment: I added what was wrong.

Comment: I don't see any code to move the first image back to the starting point once it has moved entirely off screen.

Comment: Can I add a video here to show you whats happening?

Comment: Starts out with 2 nodes and a line and the fps is <20. Then the line ends and when it "runs out" the node count becomes 0 and fps becomes 60. Than after a few seconds the line pops back up and it runs perfectly like a endless scrolling background.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
bgline2.position = CGPointMake(bgline1.size.width-1, 0)
```

This line of code somehow fixed the problem for me. I don't know how it fixed it but it did. If someone wants to explain this for me please do. I have not seen any tutorials out there that use this but it worked for me.

Rohit